# vba to compare two dynamic fields if is exisiting on other page

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub numbers()
Dim rngCell As Range
For Each rngCell In Sheets("Final").Range("F13:F" & rowLast)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Filter").Range("A1:A" & rowLast), rngCell) <> 0 And _
       Range("I" & rngCell.Row).Value <= 0 And _
         Range("D" & rngCell.Row).Value < 50 Or _
          Range("D" & rngCell.Row).Value > 59 Then

       MsgBox "Please add correct number " & rngCell
       End
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

I have this code, but I would like to set this comparing value from filter sheet column B. instead of writing numbers manually just like first line of if statement.

want to make change on this lines:

```
Range("D" & rngCell.Row).Value < 50 Or _
Range("D" & rngCell.Row).Value > 59 Then
```

Is possible to make this filter compare values from column B like `If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Filter").Range("A1:A" & rowLast), rngCell) <> 0 And _` 
?

Any advice are welcome!

Comment: Are you getting error? There's an extra `OR` in the IF

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub numbers()
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim lR_final, lR_filter As Long

lR_final = Worksheets("Final").Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
lR_filter = Worksheets("Filter").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Each rngCell In Sheets("Final").Range("F13:F" & lR_final)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Filter").Range("A1:A" & lR_filter), rngCell) <> 0 And _
       Range("I" & rngCell.Row).Value <= 0 And _
         Range("D" & rngCell.Row).Value < WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Filter").Range("B1:B" & lR_filter), rngCell) Or _
          Range("D" & rngCell.Row).Value > WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Filter").Range("B1:B" & lR_filter), rngCell) Then

       MsgBox "Please add correct number " & rngCell
       End
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Try This and let us know if it works or if it gives an error.

Comment: I am trying to do this instead writing like yours, but it seems its ignoring this line.  Range("D" & rngCell.Row).Value <> WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Filter").Range("B1:B" & rowLast), rngCell) Then

Comment: I have updated an answer so the code can handle different last rows for both the sheets.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I got the solution by myself. This code works way I wanted.                           If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Filter").Range("A1:A" & rowLast), rngCell) <> 0 And _
       Range("I" & rngCell.Row).Value <= 0 And _
       WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Filter").Range("B1:B" & rowLast), rngCell.Offset(, -2)) = 0 Then